How to reinstall or downgrade Ubuntu on a Virtual machine with software and settings intact?
I have an Ubuntu 20.04 VM on VirtualBox installed for work. Recently, it updated the OS to Ubuntu 22.04 (not sure why, maybe it auto-updated or bc of my mistakes), rendered some of my software, tools and projects not working because they're specially configured for Ubuntu 20.04 only.
Creating a new VM and reinstall all the tools can take weeks, so I wonder if there is a way to downgrade the OS back to 20.04, or re-install it with a 20.04 ISO (that I downloaded on my main PC) with all setting, files and software intact?
Thank you

Welcome to AskUbuntu! There is no way to downgrade with everything intact. The only realistic way to do this would be to create — and keep — snapshots of your VMs so that you can roll back to any point in time

A release-upgrade requires a user to ACCEPT the process before it starts; its not an automatic procedure; so someone gave it permission & then confirmed it prior to the process starting. Downgrades (any automatic form) are performed via backups; and we won't know what backup strategy you put in place, as your alternative is manually downgrade each package one-at-a-time (downgrades are catered for only package by package intentionally; backups the automatic method) OR you maybe able to non-destructively re-install (you gave no specifics as to install; mentioning only release details)
